# Remove PhpStorm blue tab underline

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm

How can I remove the blue underline?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

ATM you cannot.

It was introduced to make currently active tab more visible in Darcula GUI Theme ([IDEA-131683](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-131683), [IDEA-103206](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-103206)) where tab backgrounds are too similar. Check comments there (mainly first ticket).

So far the best match would be https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-168708 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

In meantime please try **Active IntelliJ Tab Highlighter plugin** -- it may provide such functionality (was created by one of the users before this new tab highlighting functionality was introduced) -- it's customizable so may not have such underline at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your image link is broken.

**Please, try to follow this path step by step:**

File/Settings/Editor/Color Scheme/General

This General screen can remove with checkbox disable all underline
 Also, you can look this image.
I hope have been helping you.
[screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xJflIK7W0BQCkYKj25xQn0BqUVHLh_XC/view?usp=sharing)